# error while saving data from page to xml file

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have 2 accounts one is confirm and other one is unconfirm. whe user click on reportComparison button, it shows data of both accounts. if user think data is wrong he can change it from available dropdowns,dropdown is also on the same page. and then he can add remarks to it in given text area. there is one bureau id which is automatically selected. no the problem is when user click on report buton to save data of accounts in xml file it throws object reference error,although I have add conditional checks.if value is null for anayaccout then replace it with 0.

here's my code,

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveReport(int BureauID, string Note, int? Incorrect_CustomerAccountId, int? Incorrect_C_CustomerAccountId, int? Correct_CustomerAccountId, int? Correct_C_CustomerAccountId)
        {
            try
            {
                var report = new Report
                {
                    BureauID = BureauID,
                    Note = Note,
                };

                report.InCorrectMapping.CustomerAccount = Incorrect_CustomerAccountId.HasValue
                    ? new VM_CustomerAccount().FindDetailsById(Incorrect_CustomerAccountId.Value)
                    : null;

                report.InCorrectMapping.CCustomerAccount = Incorrect_C_CustomerAccountId.HasValue
                    ? new VM_CustomerAccount().FindDetailsById(Incorrect_C_CustomerAccountId.Value)
                    : null;

                report.CorrectMapping.CustomerAccount = Correct_CustomerAccountId.HasValue
                    ? new VM_CustomerAccount().FindDetailsById(Correct_CustomerAccountId.Value)
                    : null;

                report.CorrectMapping.CCustomerAccount = Correct_C_CustomerAccountId.HasValue
                    ? new VM_CustomerAccount().FindDetailsById(Correct_C_CustomerAccountId.Value)
                    : null;


                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Report));
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/XML/Report.xml")))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, report);
                }

                return Content("XML data saved successfully!", "text/plain");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content("Error: " + ex.Message, "text/plain");
            }
        }
```